# Azure DevOps Repo to Azure Static HTML CI/CD Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I have a static HTML website hosted in Azure Storage using the static HTML feature. I'm using Azure DevOps Git Repo as my source control.

Currently I'm manually pushing changed files Azure Storage, but would like to automate the task. The trigger would be when the master branch is updated then it should update the Azure Storage account ($web folder).

I was looking at Pipelines and started using the wizard and selected my repo. I saw the first option for "Configure your pipeline" was called HTML - Archive your static HTML project and save it with the build record.

It produces this YAML:

```
# HTML
# Archive your static HTML project and save it with the build record.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(build.sourcesDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
```

Questions:

1. Is this the right template to start with to accomplish what I'm trying to do? If yes, what do I need to add/modify to accomplish my goal?
2. Is there another approach to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right path. You will need to update your inputs to be similar to:

```
inputs:
rootFolderOrFile: ‘$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dist’
archiveType: ‘zip’
archiveFile: ‘$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip’
replaceExistingArchive: true
```

There's also a blog out there that you can reference for this:

https://medium.com/@matthewleak/deploying-a-static-website-to-azure-storage-using-azure-devops-fa0bed457d07

Comment: I have the same setup as OP, but the Archive task is including the .git file and all its content in the zip archive. How would I exclude the .get from being in the zip archive?